# Exerciser tool - how to slow down input events?

Tags: android

I'm trying to run the exerciser monkey tool, but I keep getting ANRs in random places, even google apps. I think this is partially due to the rate at which the clicks are being delivered. I tried to use the throttle param, but it doesn't appear to be honored. Running like this:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.my.package -v 50 --throttle 4000
```

so I'm expecting a 4 second delay between events - am I misinterpreting the meaning of that parameter? It still seems like events are being sent as fast as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to work, so this feels like a bug in the current monkey. I have [filed an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42037) on this.

Comment: Curses. Thanks for verifying.